# How to get first values from diferent columns at same time?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get firsts values from diferent columns to make a data frame, but I I get stranded at one point and don't know how to solve it. Imagine you're using gapminder and want to get three higer gdppercap values for each region/year. How would you do it with dplyr?

Thanks.

Comment: Writing your question with "imagine you're using...." is not a helpful way to write a question. Please review how to write a good question. Specifically, please include sample data (with `dput`), what you have tried so far, and where you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring that region is `continent`; if it were `country`, then this filter would return all rows, since each `country`/`year` combination occurs only once (so "top 3" means nothing special).

```r
library(dplyr)
gapminder::gapminder %>%
  group_by(continent, year) %>%
  slice_max(desc(gdpPercap), n = 3) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 168 x 6
#    country       continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
#    <fct>         <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
#  1 Lesotho       Africa     1952    42.1   748747      299.
#  2 Guinea-Bissau Africa     1952    32.5   580653      300.
#  3 Eritrea       Africa     1952    35.9  1438760      329.
#  4 Lesotho       Africa     1957    45.0   813338      336.
#  5 Eritrea       Africa     1957    38.0  1542611      344.
#  6 Ethiopia      Africa     1957    36.7 22815614      379.
#  7 Burundi       Africa     1962    42.0  2961915      355.
#  8 Eritrea       Africa     1962    40.2  1666618      381.
#  9 Lesotho       Africa     1962    47.7   893143      412.
# 10 Burundi       Africa     1967    43.5  3330989      413.
# # ... with 158 more rows
```